# Как обновить в приложении библиотеку, ранее созданную и скомпилированную в файл *.aar

Tags: library, project

Я создал проект (назовем его проект1), и поместил туда через Project Structure свою *.aar библиотеку, созданную в другом проекте (проект2). Потом я эту библиотеку модифицировал, и решил обновить её в проекте1, но когда я через Project Structure удалил библиотеку, а потом импортировал *.aar файл, получилось так, как будто я ничего не делал с библиотекой, то есть проект1 видит её, как старую версию, а новые методы, которые я туда дописал, не видит. Как это исправить, т.е. как обновить эту библиотеку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашёл способ, позволяющий править библиотеку, подключенную к проекту, без необходимости выхода из проекта. В settings.gradle нужно указать:

```
include ':app', ':имя_вашей_библиотеки'
project(':имя_вашей_библиотеки').projectDir = new File('путь_к_вашей_библиотеке')
```

Затем в разделе dependencies build.gradle добавить:

```
implementation project(':имя_вашей_библиотеки')
```

Очень удобный способ!